# removing duplicates in an array with new Set gives an error

Tags: javascript, typescript, spread-syntax

I am trying to remove duplicates in an array with new Set gives an error "new Set(names).slice is not a function"

```
const names = ["Mike","Matt","Nancy","Adam","Jenny","Nancy","Carl"];
const uniq = [ ...new Set(names) ];
console.log(uniq);
```

Here is the [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p1ar6y?file=src/app/app.component.ts) on stackblitz

Comment: Use `Array.from(new Set(names))` - it's more readable as well :-)

Comment: Yes you are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to fix the error by adding a `tsconfig.json` in the root of the project. It is a super simple config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6"
  }
}
```

What is happening is that TypeScript is compiling to an `es3` version of javascript which is the default if no target is configured as [shown here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) (see `--target`).

Answer (score 2):

When your code goes through the build phase and is translated from TypeScript to JavaScript, the second line you posted becomes:

```
var uniq = new Set(names).slice();
```

Personally I would consider that a TypeScript bug but I never use TypeScript so I can't say for sure.

*edit* — actually I don't think it happens unless you're targeting ES5.

Comment: Looks like an "optimisation" where spread syntax is supported only on arrays, not arbitrary iterables.

Comment: @Bergi right, and maybe it works differently if TypeScript targets ES6; I don't know much about that and I can't see anything obvious in the linked Angular setup about how to affect the TypeScript build step.

Comment: There's (at least) one open issue regarding this behavior: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8856

Comment: @Pointy Your answer is very helpful.